# Running code repeatedly while key pressed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a game in JavaScript with THREE.js. I am currently trying to figure out how to properly process keyboard input.

I have already tried a few ways to detect and process keyboard events so that my game properly responds to key down and up events immediately, however my attempts seem to cause a huge performance hit or delay.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeypress);

function onKeypress(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      //Code to execute
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      //Code to execute
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      //Code to execute
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      //Code to execute
      break;
  }
}
```

I would like this to be a continuous and smooth loop while the key is pressed, but instead I only receive one keydown event and then a few seconds later I get the repeated keys. Does anyone know how I could do this in such a way that I get a continuous smooth stream of the function being called?

[Rest of code here](https://pastebin.com/hcFmD4ez)

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code for context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to store the state of keys currently pressed by the user in a variable outside of the `keydown` event listener:

```
/* A map that stores real-time "press state" for corresponding key */
const currentKeysPressed = {};

function onKeypress(event) {

  /* Update keys pressed state for event.key to true
  signifiying the key that caused the event is now pressed */
  currentKeysPressed[event.key] = true;

  /*
  Current code unlikely to be needed:

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      //Code to execute
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      //Code to execute
      ...
      ...
  }
  */
}

/* Defined new event listener to reset key state
on key release */
function onKeyUp(event) {

  currentKeysPressed[event.key] = false;
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeypress);
window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
```

With something like the above in place, you would then update your applications render loop (and/or code where immediate response to to key state is required) so that key processing logic happens there instead.

So for instance, you might access the `currentKeysPressed` state in your applications render loop to move the player's game character by doing something along the lines of:

```
/* Example application loop for your app based on a typical threejs 
application loop */
function updateLoop() {

  if(currentKeysPressed['ArrowUp']) {
      /* Arrow up was just pressed, or is being held down by user */

      /* player.takeStepForward(); */
  }

  /* Draw the scene */
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  /* Schedule next frame for rendering */
  requestAnimationFrame(updateLoop);
}
```

Comment: Just a small correction: requestAnimationFrame at the end should be called with updateLoop as its argument.

Comment: @Håkan thanks for spotting that!