# Run the function until the mouse button is pressed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want the function to run continuously as long as the user presses the mouse button
But it runs only once and is printed once on the console
I do not know how to solve this problem
please guide me

```
  function handleBye() {
      return console.log("BYE");
    }
    function handleHello() {
      return console.log("HELLO");
    }


<button onmousedown="handleHello()">hello</button>
<button onmousedown="handleBye()">bye</button>
```

Comment: You might be looking for this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484999/running-code-repeatedly-while-key-pressed-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```js
let timer;

function stop() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}

function handleHello() {
  repeat(() => console.log("HELLO"));
}

function handleBye() {
  repeat(() => console.log("BYE"));
}

function repeat(what) {
  timer = setInterval(what, 200); // Schedule
  what(); // Also do it immediately 
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="handleHello()" onmouseup="stop()">hello</button>
<button onmousedown="handleBye()" onmouseup="stop()">bye</button>
```

Comment: After releasing the mouse key is still running. I want it to stop after releasing

Comment: So what is the purpose of the bye button then? I updated my answer with just one button. Is that what you want?

Comment: The purpose of both buttons is the same and I pressed each one so that it should be printed on the console before releasing the mouse button.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Is this what you want?